# Is it possible to store a variable from nested void Override method and return it?

Tags: java, asynchronous, return, firebase

I define global variable name `String str[]`. There is a method name getMessageArray which the type of that is `String[]` inside this method , there is another override void method from a library (jar) file. my intent is to return String array which is populated in override method , from `getMessageArray` but with the code bellow I get `null` when I debug. is there technically any way in java to fix the issue?
I need this for some purpose of using firebase.

```
public String[] getMessageArray(){
        Firebase ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long strLength;
                strLength = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                str = new String[(int) strLength];
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot iterator : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 str[i]=iterator.child("message").getValue().toString();
                    i++;
                }
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
       return str;
}
```

my question is how to store populated data , and return it as array with value in example above

Comment: This does not make sense, because the listener / data change event (which is asynchronous) is fired *after* the getMessageArray returns - and it's not possible to return something that is not yet in existance. When dealing with asynchronous events, the *entire* pipeline must be so - eg. the onDataChange would call a method that *uses* the returned data (perhaps even assigning it to a variable at that point). There are also [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), but that's another topic..

Comment: Make that variable static at class level... Everything inside class has access to it now.. no need to return as well..

Comment: so is it technically possible to make it sense to it. i mean make it work, my intent is return str whenever the method is called. and str must be populated from onDataChange (override method). is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Not with the current approach, as I previously explained. Basically: the core concept is flawed. You can't return something that doesn't exist yet. Either process the *entire* unit asynchronously or use Futures and try to coalesce it back into a synchronous model.

Comment: @Raman The reason that i want to return it , is we are trying to make a framework base on firebase

Comment: You could use a semaphore to wait for the `onDataChange` to fire and only then return. The problem is that `onDataChange` will fire *every time the data changes* (hence the name). If you're using Firebase, it helps to always think of "data synchronization points" instead of queries.

Comment: Future won't work here either. The data can change at any point in the future. There is no *resolution* to a data listener. An Observer model is the correct answer here, not trying to turn an asynchronous, real-time event stream into a static array.